# How do I view and edit this text in SAPScript?

Tags: sapscript

```
INCLUDE &T001G-TXTAB& OBJECT TEXT ID ADRS LANGUAGE &T001-SPRAS&
```

This is the line of code in my SAPScript I am editing. I need to change this text, but I can't find it in the transaction SO10?

How do I view and edit this text?

Answer (score 0):

The `&...&` part denotes a [symbol](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_srm702/helpdata/en/4e/37ae0b862135a9e10000000a42189c/frameset.htm). You will need the runtime value of the variable `T001G-TXTAB` of the printing program to determine the name of the text. You can use the [SAPscript debugger](https://help.sap.com/viewer/59204ae5e0d745628df068a6ec7591b0/7.52.5/en-US/4e2ea01d9af202e7e10000000a15822b.html) to check the value.